# Accessing my mapView var from another function: mapView = nil

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to place some annotations on a mapView from a function, but the mapView shows up as nil in the debugger.  I'm calling the below function from a different class and the call seems to work by setting up some breakpoints.  It just errors out when it tries to add the annotations array onto the mapView.

```
let temp = MapViewController()
temp.createCurrentSevereAnnotations()
```

Here's my code for the MapViewController:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

final class MapViewController : UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    // Change the Map Type from the tool bar segmented button.
//this function works fine.  mapView is not nil.
@IBAction func changeMapType(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        mapView.mapType = .Standard
    case 1:
        mapView.mapType = .Hybrid
    default:
        mapView.mapType = .Satellite

    } //^ this func works fine
 }
    //Puts an array of CustomPointAnnotation on the map.
 func createCurrentSevereAnnotations() {
    var annotations: Array = [CustomPointAnnotation]()
    let severeReports = currentSevereReports

    for item in severeReports
    {
        let annotation = CustomPointAnnotation(latitude: Double(item.lat!), longitude: Double(item.lon!))
        print("The lat is: \(item.lat!)")
        print("The lon is: \(item.lon!)")
        switch(Int(item.type!))
        {
        case 1:
            annotation.imageName = "ef0"
            annotation.type = "Tornado"
            break
        case 2:
            annotation.imageName = "wind"
            annotation.type = "Wind"
            break
        default:
            annotation.imageName = "hail"
            annotation.type = "Hail"
            break
        }
        print("item type : \(annotation.type)")
        annotation.title = item.magnitude
        annotation.subtitle = item.location
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
        annotation.time = item.time
        annotation.county = item.county
        annotation.remarks = item.remarks

        annotations.append(annotation)
    }
    print("Annotations count = \(annotations.count)") //<- works
    mapView.addAnnotations(annotations) //<- this is where mapView is nil
 }


    // The class for our CustomPointAnnotation
 class CustomPointAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var title: String? //mag
    var subtitle: String? //location
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude:Double
    var imageName: String!
    var time: String?
    var remarks : String?
    var county: String?
    var type: String?
    var comments: String?


    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }

    init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here.

```
let temp = MapViewController()
```

This is **not** the way to instantiate a view controller.

---

You should use from loading from the storyboard. [(click here to check apple documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:)

```
func instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String) -> UIViewController
```

---

Try this way to instantiate temp.

```
let temp = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MapViewControllerIdentifier") as UIViewController
self.presentViewController(temp, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**You should define a `Identifier`** **to your view controller**( I use "*MapViewControllerIdentifier*" in my sample), you can do this in the view in the `storyboard` of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to instantiate you MapViewController differently. You can instantiate from Storyboard like this:

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let mapVC =  mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mapVC") as! MapViewController
```

You need to go in your Storyboard to set the "mapVC" ID. Select your MapViewController, go into Identity Inspector (from Utilities panel on the right) and set the Storyboard ID there.

then you can present the controller (if you want):

```
presentViewController(mapVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It is normal that your MapView is nil because it comes from the Storyboard. When your controller has controls or views coming from IB you have to instantiate form the Storyboard.

Generally speaking when a ViewController is created in the Storyboard then you need to call from the Storyboard.

Comment: Also don't forget to set your delegate in case you use MKMapViewDelegate protocol in a near future.  mapView.delegate = self.

Comment: @UlyssesR and Romain  Thanks for the tip on instantiating the MapViewController, but I'm still not getting what I need.
I've tried:    'let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mapVC =  mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mapVC") as! MapViewController'  and another approach...  
'let mapVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mapVC") as! MapViewController
        mapVC.mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)'
Both ways I still get the error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION..."

Comment: Also, I did add "mapVC" as the Storyboard ID for the MapViewController

Comment: Try to remove the "final" for your class. Also did you tell your Scene in the Storyboard that MapViewController is a subclass of UIViewController? In Identity Inspector then Custom Class -> MapViewController

Comment: I tried what you mentioned and still no luck.  I'm looking into protocol and delegate ways to solve my problem.  I'm coming from a different language where this kind of stuff was pretty easy.  I just need to figure it out in Swift 2.
Thanks! Bryan